# Internet Connection Sharing via Switch

Tags: networking, internet-connection, switch, internet-sharing

i want to ask if is possible to share an internet connection via a switch.

Two raspberry pi are connected to the switch and a windows laptop that is wirelessly connected to the internet.

Is it possible for the laptop to share its internet connection through the switch?

Comment: What OS is the laptop running?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're describing exactly what Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) is.  Microsoft explains how to use it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7).

**The details:**
Essentially you're turning your laptop into a home router.  The Wi-Fi adapter becomes the WAN and the ethernet adapter becomes the LAN.  Just like a home router, your laptop will become a gateway with a static IP on the LAN, it will serve DHCP to clients on the LAN, and it will accept DNS requests from the LAN and forward Internet-addressed ones to the WAN.

**The alternative:**
Use a wireless bridge.  Some inexpensive home routers (e.g. ASUS, TP-Link) support being used as a wireless bridge.

Comment: I enable ics sharing but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: So i need to set the laptop default gateway at rpis ?

Comment: I set lan adapter ip as default gw, still nothing.

Comment: Just use DHCP on the Pis.  This is an option, correct?

Comment: Using ICS, I have always had to assign static IPs on the client. For the host, ICS automatically assigns a static IP (e.g., `192.168.137.1`) to the Ethernet port which connects to the client(s). Then I can connect the host directly to a single client device, or connect the host to an Ethernet switch. All clients (if using a switch) should have a unique, but static IP address (e.g., `192.168.137.2`, `192.168.137.3`, etc.) and have the default gateway (of the client device) set to the static IP of the host (e.g., `192.168.137.1`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Windows Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7) on your laptop to share an internet connection with the Raspberry Pis, or you can use one of the Raspberry Pis as a router.  There are lots of ways of doing that.  Running [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi) on it is just one option.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to use laptop to recieve internet via wifi, then redristribute it via a simple switch as ICS includes its own DHCP implementation. You must also configure your Raspberri Pi's to use the laptop as a proxy. Also, you must consider that when sharing a network connection through a switch, it is possible you may need to use a 'crossover cable' from your laptop to the switch or some switches have autoMDI(MDIX) at the uplink port to allow use of a standard ethernet cord. For reference, read especially bottom 'Uplink Port' section, http://www.pcweenie.com/hni/lan/lan3.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you need a router, not a switch. You can use your laptop to double as a router, but you will most likely need two network interfaces.

**Long answer:**

Internet connection sharing typically means that one device connects to both the internet and the local network and has different IP addresses on these networks.

The IP packets coming from the local network and destined for the internet are unpacked from the [link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_reference_model#Link_layer) packet (where the source and destination MAC address is located) and placed in a new link layer packet on the internet link based on the target IP address in the [internet layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_reference_model#Internet_layer) part of the packet. This is called [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing), hence the name, router.

Often this process also involves [NAT or Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which means the router also replaces the source IP address and maintains a state for the connection so it can direct any incoming related packets back to the original sender host, in this case one of your Pi's.

In contrast to that, a switch is doesn't touch anything in any of the packets, it simply receives a packet on one port and reads the link level header's destination MAC address, then outputs the packed on the port corresponding to that target MAC address.

And for the sake of completeness: a hub is a dumb switch, it outputs every packet it receives on all ports, except the original one.

**In conclusion:** you will need a device that acts as a router. That device will in most cases need a separate link for the internet connection and the local network. You could for example use your LAN port for internet and your WLAN port for your local network or the other way around, but you are probably much better off buying a router as they are fairly cheap and it will enable your laptop to be used as a portable device.

Comment: I believe he/she is asking if the Windows 7 PC can be used as a router. Not that many routers will allow the WAN side to be wireless.